# High availability open source SQL database solution for Rails application

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, high-availability, open-source

I'm researching a topic of high availability database for a Rails application. I'm looking for Open Source based solutions.

At the moment our system is running on one application host + one db host, which means any of this two goes down I'm in trouble. I'd much prefer to have this configuration doubled and if possible running each on different site (but this is not a requirement).

The first thought was active-active replication, but it seems Postgresql is weak at this and MySQL is not rock solid neither (http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/15/mysql-myisam-active-active-clustering-looking-for-trouble/). I'm thinking about a VoltDB, which seems like a sexy topic and can be used with Rails it seems.

Log sharing seems like a nice idea, but I'm quite new with this concept and I'm wondering about cost of such solution and how ie. MySQL is going to work with it. And it excludes any way of running the application at two different sites I guess.

I could really use some tips here, so feel free to ask questions and propose solutions. I'll edit this post to add any necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HaProxy.

You can  configure Haproxy to be failover, replication , or  loadbalancer

http://www.alexwilliams.ca/blog/2009/08/10/using-haproxy-for-mysql-failover-and-redundancy/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for mentioning HaProxy. I'm aware of it, but I'm little worried about master-master replication of MySQL (have you seen a link I've pasted in my post). In my situation I'd not use any slaves nodes (as they are unnecessary -- performance is not a problem for me).

Comment: @dpc.core.info Your link is about Mysql clustering with myisam tables on shared disk storage across multiple servers. That's a very specific environment they are talking about. General master master replication with shared nothing servers is not that brittle.

Answer (score 1):

VoltDB supports HA natively, we actually want people to run it on a cluster of commodity servers.

Comment: Just found this VoltDB and it looks very scalable.